# Facebook page/posts only returning limited results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API to look at posts from public pages.
Previously, I was able to page through all of a pages posts, back to its inception (from today back to 2014, for example).
But now this seems to be not possible anymore: if I page through a pages posts, the `next` key disappears eventually. I have tried using `cursors['after']` instead of `paging['next']`, but this stops at the same point. So far I'm unable to determine if this limit is time based (i.e. you can't get posts older than 4 months) or amount-based (only X posts back into the past), because calls to the API do return posts up to 5 years back.
I.e. the first 200 posts I get back are reverse-chronological for this year, and then at the very end I get a couple of posts from 2012 or 2014.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9"
node = "/%s/posts" % page_id 
fields = "/?fields=message,link,created_time,type,name,id," + \
                        "comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares,reactions" + \
                        ".limit(0).summary(true)"
parameters = "&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (50, access_token)
next_page = "&after=%s" % (statuses['paging']['cursors']['after'])
url = base + node + fields + parameters + next_page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a current bug with the /posts endpoint. You can follow the current status here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2297783020445879/